# Confused about diagonal matix notation

Tags: matrices, notation

Reading a book of physics I found the following definition of diagonal matrix:

$$A_{ij}= A_{ii}\delta_{ij}$$

I understand a diagonal matrix has only diagonal elements nonzero, but is the previous notation correct?

I'm somehow confused because if we choose $A_{ij}$ with $i\neq j $ (f.e $A_{12}$) then we need to use $A_{11}$ from the right side, which seems a bit forced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This notation uses the [Kronecker delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta) $\delta_{ij}$, which is $1$ when $i=j$ and $0$ otherwise $($so, $0$ outside the diagonal$)$.

Albeit correct, I must say this is a very lazy definition of diagonal matrix.

Comment: Thanks. I know. But isn't it forced to use $A_{ii}$ in the second case?

Comment: What is 'the second case'?

Comment: I different from j (where you put 0)

Comment: What if we write $A=A_{ij}\delta_{ij}$, isn't it better?

Comment: $A$ is a matrix, $A_{ij}\delta_{ij}$ is a number. If $i\neq j$, $\delta_{ij} = 0$ so $A_{ij} = A_{ii}\cdot 0 = 0$, regardless of the value of $A_{ii}$.

Comment: Hmm..well yeah, it's just that the notation don't convince me, not sure why...but thanks

Comment: Don't worry, it's definitely a lazy way to define diagonal matrices.

Answer (score 0):

It's correct, if $i=j$, $A_{ij}=A_{ii}\delta_{ij}=A_{ii}\cdot 1 = A_{ii}$

if $i\ne j$, $A_{ij}=A_{ii}\delta_{ij}=A_{ii}\cdot 0 = 0$

Comment: Thanks. I know. But isn't it forced to use $A_{ii}$ in the second case?

Comment: it will be multiplied by $0$ right? I think it is just a compact way of writing.